# SoapServer behind Symfony 3 controller not calling wrapped method

Tags: php, symfony, soap

### Overview

I'm trying to put a SOAP server inside a Symfony controller as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/soap_web_service.html.

I'm using PHP2WSDL to generate the WSDL (after having failed to create a valid one by hand!). I have a service class with a bunch of methods that will be exposed via SOAP. And the Symfony controller will shovel the POST data into the `SoapServer` instance and barf out the yukky XML response back to the client.

But I'm pretty sure that `SoapServer` is not calling the methods on my service class. I can see from `SoapServer::getFunctions` that all the PHP2WSDL `@soap` annotated methods have been registered by my `SoapServer` instance, but nothing my methods are supposed to do seems to be happening; no logging, not even `throw new \Exception('@#!?!');` on the first line.

The actual symptom I have is that, after the `SoapClient` tries to `__soapCall` a method (in the *other* application), it expects to have received some `SoapHeader`s (which my method might be setting; I just don't know) but the response headers are empty.

### Code

Commented lines are things I've been using to try and debug.

#### Symfony controller

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    const SERVICE_URI = 'http://example.com/api';

    public function wsdlAction()
    {
        $log = new Logger('api');

        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        $response->setContent($this->makeWsdl());

        // $log->debug(sprintf('[%s] WSDL response', __METHOD__));

        return $response;
    }

    public function operationAction(Request $request)
    {
        $log = new Logger('api');

        try {
            $wsdlFile = tmpfile();
            $wsdlPath = stream_get_meta_data($wsdlFile)['uri'];
            file_put_contents($wsdlPath, $this->makeWsdl());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $log->error(sprintf('[%s] Couldn\'t create the temporary WSDL file for SoapServer: "%s"', __METHOD__, $e->getMessage()));
            throw $e;
        }

        // $c = file_get_contents($wsdlPath);
        // $log->debug(sprintf('[%s] Created WSDL temporary file in %s: %s', __METHOD__, $wsdlPath, $c));

        $server = new SoapServer(
            $wsdlPath,
            [
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            ]
        );

        // $log->debug(sprintf('[%s] Created server', __METHOD__));
        $server->setObject(new MyService($server, $log));
        // $log->debug(sprintf('[%s] Set server object', __METHOD__));
        // foreach ($server->getFunctions() as $f) {
        //     $log->debug(sprintf('[%s] SOAP function: %s', __METHOD__, (string) $f));
        // }

        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
        // $log->debug(sprintf('[%s] Create new response', __METHOD__));

        ob_start();
        // $log->debug(sprintf('[%s] Calling server->handle(%s)', __METHOD__, $request->getContent()));
        $server->handle($request->getContent());
        // $log->debug(sprintf('[%s] Setting response content', __METHOD__));
        $response->setContent(ob_get_clean());

        // $log->debug(sprintf('[%s] operate response', __METHOD__));

        return $response;
    }

    private function makeWsdl()
    {
        $wsdlGenerator = new PHP2WSDL\PHPClass2WSDL(MyService::class, self::SERVICE_URI);
        $wsdlGenerator->generateWSDL(true);

        return $wsdlGenerator->dump();
    }
}
```

This controller mostly "works". I mean, you can call the route for the WSDL and you get the WSDL. And you can call the route for the operations and it does all the work up to `$server->handle($request->getContent());` where it throws an exception.

#### MyService

```
class MyService
{
    private $server;
    private $log;

    public function __construct(SoapServer $server, Logger $log)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->log = $log;
        // $this->log->debug(sprintf('[%s] __construct called', __METHOD__));
    }

    /**
     * @soap
     */
    public function Login(array $parameters = [])
    {
        // throw new \Exception('Login throws immediately');

        // $this->log->debug(sprintf('[%s] Login called: %s', __METHOD__, json_encode($parameters)));

        $this->server->addSoapHeader(new SoapHeader(
            'http://example.com/api',
            'AuthHeader',
            ['Token' => 'fake-token']
        ));

        return true;
    }
}
```

The WSDL is generated from this class by PHP2WSDL which seems to be working perfectly.

The external application that calls my controller is throwing an exception because it's expecting to get this `AuthHeader` SOAP header in the SOAP response that comes from my `DefaultController`. But it isn't finding one. But whether or not my attempt to use `addSoapHeader` here is correct, I can't see that this `Login` method is even being called.

#### The external application

```
$this->client = new SoapClient('http://example.com/api/wsdl', [
    'trace' => 1,
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'location' => 'http://example.com/api',
]);

...

$response = $this->client->__soapCall(
    'Login',
    ['username' => '', 'password' => ''],
    [],
    null,
    $outputHeaders
);

...

if ($outputHeaders['AuthHeader']) {
    ...
```

This is the code that ultimately throws the exception when `$outputHeaders['AuthHeader']` is not set. From here, I can dump the SOAP requests and responses. Here's the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/api/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" soap-env:encodingstyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <body>
    <login>
      <parameters xsi:type="ns2:Map">
        <item>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">username</key>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string"></value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">password</key>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string"></value>
        </item>
      </parameters>
    </login>
  </body>
</envelope>
```

And the response, of course, is empty; as are the output headers.

This code is the "legacy" bit that I can't change. For a bit more background: it calls a real, third-party SOAP service and what I'm trying to do at the moment is build a mock of that service that can be used for testing.

Comment: I've given up on trying to build a working SOAP service for my mock and I'm just returning some static SOAP XML from this controller instead :-(